# Models.DateField Format issues

Tags: django, django-models, django-1.7

I have a model, which has a date field

```
date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="DOB")
```

I would like to format it to save dates in the format `dd/MM/yyyy`, but everything I have tried fails.

I think the default must be `YYYY-MM-dd` because that is how it saves to my database. Trying to submit dates in a different format gives the error:

```
[u"'17/01/1970' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]
```

I have tried using [Date Widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/widgets/) but am having a few issues getting it to be compatible with my models.py

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change this by overriding `input_formats` on the `DateField` in your form. This is covered [pretty well in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#datefield). The default date formats are

```
['%Y-%m-%d',      # '2006-10-25'
'%m/%d/%Y',       # '10/25/2006'
'%m/%d/%y']       # '10/25/06'
```

or

```
['%Y-%m-%d',      # '2006-10-25'
'%m/%d/%Y',       # '10/25/2006'
'%m/%d/%y',       # '10/25/06'
'%b %d %Y',      # 'Oct 25 2006'
'%b %d, %Y',      # 'Oct 25, 2006'
'%d %b %Y',       # '25 Oct 2006'
'%d %b, %Y',      # '25 Oct, 2006'
'%B %d %Y',       # 'October 25 2006'
'%B %d, %Y',      # 'October 25, 2006'
'%d %B %Y',       # '25 October 2006'
'%d %B, %Y']      # '25 October, 2006'
```

Depending on whether or not you are using localization in your settings.

You appear to be looking for `%d/%m/%y`, which isn't a default format.

Comment: What?! Django only accepts these formats? What about %d/%m/%Y which is used in most of the world?

Comment: This only applies to the forms DateField, notice that the OP specified models.DateField.  The models.DateField to_python method invokes the utils.dateparse parse_date method, which only allows %Y-%m-%d.

Comment: The OP mentioned the Date widgets, which was enough to assume that the issue was specific to a ModelForm and not a Model itself. I do appreciate your answer though, because not everyone is going to hit this question because that got the error from using a form.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to extend DateField to handle other date formats, such as by converting them yourself during the save, instructions [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-model-fields/).  For reference, I just had to deal with this problem and my solution looked like this:

```
class HWDateField(models.DateField):
def to_python(self, value):
    if value is None:
        return value
    return super(HWDateField,self).to_python(parseDate(value))
```

Where parseDate was a conversion function I had already written.

Comment: How were  you able to achive this?

Comment: @FightWithCode if you could clarify your question, I'd be happy to edit the answer to add more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can not set the `input_formats` on the model's field, but only on the form's field. With a ModelForm, and fields auto generated based on the model, you redefine/customize what you need as [documented here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields).

"[...] you want complete control over of a field, you can do this by declaratively specifying fields like you would in a regular Form.". Here's my example :

```
class UserCreationForm(BaseUserCreationForm):
    birth_date = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y'])

    class Meta(BaseUserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "first_name", "last_name", "email", "birth_date")
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply setting the timezone/locale in settings will adjust datetime widget to correct format.